# Why is my MVC2 Page HtmlEncoding a html helper but only when it is inside a link tag?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-2

I have this really strange problem. I have written a HtmlHelper...

```
public static class MaterResourceLocationHelper
    {
        public static HtmlString GetMasterLocation(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
        {
            return new 
                HtmlString(ConfigurationManager
                               .AppSettings["MasterResourceLocation"]);
        }
    }
```

When I put the following on an MVC2 View...

```
<%= Html.GetMasterLocation() %>
```

In the view source I get...

```
http://localhost/esd.myapp.com/
```

However as soon as I try to use it in context like this...

```
<link href='<%= Html.GetMasterLocation() %> 
               /Css/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css' 
      rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

I get this in the view source...

```
<link 
    href="../../Views/Shared/%3C%25=%20Html.GetMasterLocation()%20%25%3E%20/Css/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css" 
    rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Im really confused as to why that happens?

Comment: Can you post more code? I was not able to reproduce your problem. Also, is it just a typo that you have single quotes, but then double quotes as the output????

Answer (score 0):

The ASP view engine has some funny rules around when these tags get evaluated and when they don't. Try this:

```
<link href='<%= Html.GetMasterLocation() + "/Css/jquery-ui-1.8.2.custom.css"%>' 
  rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

It seems like the `<%= %>` tags only get evaluated if they represent the entire HTML attribute. Otherwise the engine just treats it literally. What you're seeing here is not HTML-encoding of the result, but URL encoding of the literal value between quotes.

Comment: No, the OP's code should work. I just tried it to verify and it works as written against my MVC2 project...